# Update: java file.delete() directory create should fail for a test (how?)

Tags: java

currently I have a API that should test file deletion on a service, however I don't know how I can I test for a unsuccessful delete?

Currently my code is like that:

```
if(!file.exists()) {
    return "NOT_EXISTS";
} else if(!file.delete()) {
    return "FILE_NOT_DELETED";
}
return "";
```

So if the file could not be delete due to a locked file or anything it should block.
Currently I inject a TemporaryFolder for my tests and tried to set the file / folder to read only, however that won't work, do I have any other possibilities to test that cases?

Also the same thing for directory creation which is way harder.

Comment: Since this line is accessible you need to put any return so why is it pointless.

Comment: or try deleting a directory which is non empty

Comment: Also this is just sample code, if {} else if {}  else, but I omitted the last else which people could do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java 1.7 you can try to use FileLock for this file or directory, then you'll be unable to delete it.

For example, if you use jUnit, create FileLock in @Before annotated method, then file.delete() in tests will return false or fails. Here is an abstract example, just test your logic in testDelete()

```
FileLock fileLock;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    File file = new File("d:/test");
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
    FileChannel channel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
    fileLock = channel.tryLock();

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    fileLock.release();
}

@Test
public void testDelete() {
    File tempFile = new File("d:/test");
    Boolean resutl = tempFile.delete();

    assertFalse(resutl);
}
```

Comment: Basically what i did was creating a RandomAccessFile. However that only works for files and not directories, we also have cases where the same thing happens for a Directory

Comment: @christian-schmitt I've edited my answer. Now it shows, how to use FileLock. It supports lock for directories too

Comment: do you mean, you'll be unable to create new subdirectories, while rootdir is locked? if so, then yes, mkdirs() will fail too.

Comment: thanks, that's what I wanted ;) however mostly this should simulate an I/O Error, in this case it will send `String` commands back to a printer which could then react based on that (print an exception sheet), etc..

Comment: Hey, RandomAccessFile doesn't work on directories, it will give me a Exception of "no access"

Comment: hm, seems it's not possible to open FileChannel for directories, although it seemed to be possible at the least for Linux. sorry, never thought about it. hope you'll find a solution

Comment: yeah Windows sucks, however we cross develop Linux/Mac/Windows.. so ... however on Linux/Mac even a simple setReadOnly() works.. on Windows this gives false.. Anytime Anywhere

Answer (score 3):

Change the permissions of `file` so that the executing user can not delete it. This should fail  `file.delete()`.

Comment: That somehow didn't worked out, while we tried file.setReadOnly it wouldn't work somehow.

Comment: "Somehow" as in ...? Please be more specific.